# Trying to Cout the return of a function

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I'm having trouble with this code:

```
string output_date(int day, int month, int year){
    string date;
    if ((day > 0 && day <= 30) && (month > 0 && month <= 12) && (year >= 2013)){
        switch (month){
          case 1: date = day + " JAN " + year; break;
          case 2: date = day + " FEB " + year; break;
          case 3: date = day + " MAR " + year; break;
          case 4: date = day + " APR " + year; break;
          case 5: date = day + " MAY " + year; break;
          case 6: date = day + " JUN " + year; break;
          case 7: date = day + " JUL " + year; break;
          case 8: date = day + " AUG " + year; break;
          case 9: date = day + " SEP " + year; break;
          case 10: date = day + " OCT " + year; break;
          case 11: date = day + " NOV " + year; break;
          case 12: date = day + " DEC " + year; break;
        }
    }
    return date;
}
```

when I try and do:

```
cout << output_date(22,12,2013);
```

nothing comes up. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your function name in the signature and the calling location do not match. Is that a typo, or the problem?

Comment: `" JAN "` is not a `std::string`, so the additions are pointer additions. `day + " JAN " + year` is a `const char*` pointing who-knows-where.

Comment: An SSCCE would be optimal for these types of questions.

Comment: You will need to use a `std::ostringstream` to build your resulting `std::string`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Edited it.

Comment: It's interesting that you reject a `day` value greater than 30.

Comment: And you try to detect bad parameter values, but you don't do anything if there's an error; you just return `date` without explicitly initializing it. (I *think* that gives you an empty string.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using stringstream and returning a string from the stream:

```
stringstream date;
    if ((day > 0 && day <= 30) && (month > 0 && month <= 12) && (year >= 2013)){
        switch (month){
          case 1: date << day << " JAN " << year; break;
          case 2: date << day << " FEB " << year; break;
          //yadda yadda.....
        }
    }
return date.str();
```

for this you need to include the header`<sstream>`

Comment: Or use `std::to_string`. I would use a map/array for the month names anyway.

Comment: @chris I would also use a map, but it seems a more basic approach would be better for the user.

Comment: I'd factor the "day" and "year" bit out of the switch too.

Answer (score 0):

- What am i doing wrong?

First thing you doing wrong is not using debugger.

Second thing you doing wrong is adding integers to string literal. For example, `" DEC "` is a string literal which has pointer type `char const *`. Result of expression

```
day + " DEC " + year
```

is a `char const *` pointer pointing to unknown area of memory. In your case this unknown area was filled with zeroes, that's why you got empty string of type `char const *` as result. (This was my case too, when I ran your program in debugger)

You assigned this empty string to `data`, that's why you got empty output.